# Using Fetch API with cross-fetch polyfill to upload file on file-input change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, fetch-api

I'm using the Fetch API with the cross-fetch polyfill  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch

Been farting around on SO for several hours trying to get file upload working using it.  No matter what I do, I can't seem to avoid the 'unsupported BodyInit type' error.

```
<input
    name="file"
    type="file"
    onChange={event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      var f = event.target.files[0];
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", f);

      fetch("/my-api", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
      });
    }}
  />
```

Here's a runnable example: https://codesandbox.io/s/v08lpj24wy

Of course, I wouldn't do this sort of thing inside an onChange handler directly, but the example illustrates the error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out your `import fetch from "cross-fetch"` is shimming fetch incorrectly, by breaking the parsing of blobs and FormData. Just remove the import and see that everything works.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` returns a promise. It doesn't do anything until you call `then`

**edit**

If you call `fetch` with a `Request` object the error dissapears

```
var req = new Request("/my-api", {
          method: "POST",
          body: data
        });

fetch(req)
    .then(() => console.log("ok"))
    .catch(() => console.error("not ok"));
```

Comment: it doesn't even get that far...have a look at the runnable example.

Comment: I did, but forgot to check the browser console, only saw codesandbox's one. I got the fix

Answer (score 0):

Actually that's an issue with github's fetch that cross-fetch uses to fetch on the browser environment. http://github.com/github/fetch/issues/601

> You can't pass a file directly as body. You must take the 2nd approach
>   by wrapping it in a FormData. When passing a FormData to body, you
>   must not set any Content-Type header for the request. Instead, the
>   browser will choose the appropriate multipart/form-data value.